# get number of UIDs created in firebase google authentication provider

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm working on an app using Ionic2 and Firebase.

**I want to display the number of users who have signed in to my app.
Is there any way to find it?**

I have used the Google Authentication Provider to let the people sign in to my app. This part is working perfectly with the following function:

```
signin(){
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
              // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
              var token = result.credential.accessToken;
              // The signed-in user info.
              var user = result.user;
              // ...
            }).catch(function(error) {
              // Handle Errors here.
            });
    }
```

After signing in, any user's data can accessed by the implementation of the follow code:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

I want to display the number of users who have signed in to my app.
Is there any way to find it?? Kindly help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to determine the (number of) users that are current signed in to your app using Firebase Authentication.

The easiest way I know to implement something like that would be to use the Realtime Database's and model something similar to this [sample presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample).

Comment: Yes., it is giving some idea! `.info/connected` this will give the result in `snap.val()` as for all the people connected or just for the single user?

Comment: The `.info/connected` value is for the current user. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Comment: Thanks. I'm planning to store the details of the Users during their sign up and then once I wanted to count, I can use the numchild() and get it done. Is that a good technique? But in case of a large number of Users, it may be a failure ryt!